# Scrolling text with Lazarus in Raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, lazarus, freepascal

I am trying to do a scrolling text marquee component work in a Raspberry Pi 2 with  raspbian(debian)- linux. I am using FPC 3.0 and Lazarus 1.6.

I have the next code doing the scrolling  and all is working well, except for a problem.

If i have a text with accents, such as: "Isto não está certo", I can see the text showing in my component as "Isto n?o est? certo" and right after It shows the text correctly as it should: "Isto não está certo". 
It´s too fast, but I can see it occurs in the screen.

I believe it´s not an encoding problem otherwise the text allways will be showing wrong.

In Windows machine, the same program made with Lazarus 1.6 and FPC 3.0(same version as used in Linux), It doens´t shows this problem.

My windows machine certainly have many more processing power than my raspberry.

Here is the procedure  of my component responsible to scrolling the text.

What am I doing wrong?

I expect have posted all informations about the problem.

This procedure is triggered with a timer.

```
var FMemoryBitmap:TBitmap;
     FScrollScreenPos :Integer
     FScrollCurrentChar : Integer;
     FScrollPartString  : String; //partial text to render when I have long text
     FScrollText : String; //Text to scrolling. For sample: "Isto não está certo"
....
procedure TRioMarquee.DoScroll(Restart: Boolean);
var
  ARect : TRect;
  OutY  : Integer;
begin
   { Set colors }
    Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
    FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;

   { When restarting, set default values }
    if Restart then begin
     Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
     FScrollScreenPos   := ClientWidth;
     FScrollCurrentChar := 1;
     FScrollPartString  := '';
    end;
    { Clear the bitmap }
    ARect := Rect(0,0,FMemoryBitmap.Width,FMemoryBitmap.Height);
    FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(ARect);

    { Exit if there is no text to scroll }
    if Length(FScrollText) > 0 then begin
      { Decrease the current output position }
      Dec(FScrollScreenPos,FScrollAmount);

      { Remove text from the beginning until the scrolling position is around 0 }
      if (FScrollScreenPos < 0) then begin
        if Length(FScrollPartString) > 0 then while (FScrollScreenPos+TextWidth(FScrollPartString[1]) < 0) do begin
          Inc(FScrollScreenPos,TextWidth(FScrollPartString[1]));
          Delete(FScrollPartString,1,1);
        end;
      end;

      { Fill up text at the end until PartString is wider than the client rectangle }
      while FScrollScreenPos+TextWidth(FScrollPartString) < ClientWidth do begin
        FScrollPartString := FScrollPartString+FScrollText[FScrollCurrentChar];
        Inc(FScrollCurrentChar);
        if FScrollCurrentChar > Length(FScrollText) then begin
           FScrollCurrentChar := 1;
        end;
      end;

      { Output the Text to the memory bitmap }
      FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.TextOut(FScrollScreenPos,0,FScrollPartString);

      { Now draw the memory bitmap }
      Canvas.Draw(0,0,FMemoryBitmap);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I solved the problem. I changed all var string  to widestring